# I want to have an sql update query statement that will update the number of items of table called people

Tags: postgresql

I want to have an sql update query statement that will update the number of items of a table called people that has more than 400 items and set them to 400.

the logic will look like this:

Given a org id

Find people with claps > 400

Update number to 400.

I tried this but did not work, because i need also need to check the org id.

```
update people set "availableClaps" = 400
where "availableClaps" > 400 in (select id from people)
```

Comment: Why have you tagged four different databases? Which one are you actually using? It would also be helpful to include something more descriptive that "did not work" - what error you got, or why the outcome wasn't what you expected. Sample data and expected results is usually helpful too - see [mre].

Comment: in the tags sections they asked to tag at least 5

Comment: @SheriffSulemana No, at most 5 and you should not tag irrelevant RDBMS. Only tag the ones you are actually using. I have removed all the RDBMSes and you can [edit] the question to tag the one specific one you are using.

Comment: The question wizard says "Add up to 5 tags...", not at least 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass in the `orgId` value (you can use a named bind variable `:orgId` or a static value, like `42`):

```sql
UPDATE people
SET   "availableClaps" = 400
WHERE "availableClaps" > 400
AND   orgId = :orgId
```

Answer (score 0):

If "given a org id" means that you'll get it as a parameter, then you could

```
UPDATE people p
   SET p."availableClaps" = 400
 WHERE     p."availableClaps" > 400
       AND p.org_id = :par_org_id;           --> this
```

(`:par_org_id` represents a bind variable here; you might need to use something else, depending on how and where you get that value from.)

---

(BTW, if you use Oracle, it kind of *hates* mixed letter case and identifiers enclosed into double quotes; get rid of them, if you can. Otherwise you'll always have to reference them using double quotes and match letter case *exactly* as while creating the table.)

Comment: I use postgresql

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case (as far as UPDATE is concerned)

Comment: @SheriffSulemana: in Postgres, the use of quoted identifiers is also [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)